# Dynamically separate web content between multiple pages

Tags: html, css, web

I want to create a web page that contains information about various versions of my code in a tabular form, in reverse chronological order. Sample shown below.

```
Number    Release Date   End Date     Requires           Release Note   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
3.2       12/31/2013     03/31/2014   Foo 1.0, Bar 2.1   [Link]
3.1       11/30/2013     01/31/2014   Foo 0.8, Bar 2.0   [Link]
3.0       10/15/2013     01/07/2014   Foo 0.8, Bar 2.0   [Link]
...
1.0       06/30/2013     09/15/2013   Foo 0.5, Bar 1.6   [Link]
```

I have this table ready, created using HTML and CSS. However, as the number of releases increase, this table will become too long. I don't want to throw away the older release information. Is it possible to automatically move part of the table to a new HTML file, say by configuring CSS or some other means?

This is what the result will look like:

```
Number    Release Date   End Date     Requires           Release Note   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
9.2       12/31/2016     03/31/2017   Foo 6.0, Bar 8.1   [Link]
9.1       11/30/2016     01/31/2017   Foo 5.8, Bar 7.0   [Link]
9.0       10/15/2016     01/07/2017   Foo 5.8, Bar 7.0   [Link]
...
7.0       06/30/2016     09/15/2017   Foo 5.5, Bar 6.6   [Link]

[Older releases]
```

`[Older releases]` being a hyperlink to the other HTML file. I prefer not to manually move the HTML from one file to another every time there's a new release?

I am new to web designing, and do not know where to look for such things. If HTML/CSS cannot achieve this, what else should I read which will help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the content is only text, and it wouldn't take ages to load it, I recommend using jQuery - either some pagination plugin or just make a link "Show all" which shows the rest of the releases.

This means you would load all the releases at once but show them in chunks..

Pagination plugins you'll find from google, [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) is good but I believe you don't need anythingh that complicated.

You can create your own simple "Show all" feature too. Basicly:

HTML

```
[Your release table here]

<a href="#" class="show-all">Show all</a>

<div class="rest-of-the-releases" style="display:none">
    Data data data
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.show-all').click(function() {
    $('.rest-of-the-releases').fadeIn();
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Checkout the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y45mf/)

Answer (score 2):

Pagination of results is normally done in the server which gets and sends only the content needed for the page of results to the browser. This keeps the page load and page speed in the browser fast.

See this [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20161107163939/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/ASPScripts/PrintPage.asp?REF=/webtech/072101-1.shtml) in asp.net